# CouchDB automatic archiving

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I have an angular application using local storage (PouchDB) which automatically sync with a CouchDB database on a remote server.

As I would like to limit my application size, I would like to be able to archive automatically from CouchDB based on a condition.

Here is what I've imagined:

- I save a file in my localDB which sync with my CouchDB
- After few days, I tell my localDB to archive this file
- My localDB delete the file and CouchDB automatically copy the file into another internal database (not sync'ed with the localDB) before removing it.

You could say that I can do this within my app but the problem is when the app is used offline, it cannot directly access the remote CouchDB to copy into another database.

So my question is, can CouchDB automatically copy a doc into another database (within same CouchDB) based on a value in the doc (archived = true for example)? If not, what would you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To preserve the last non-deleted version of each document**, you could set up a continuous replication between your "data" and "backup" couchdb databases with a filter function that prevents `_deleted` docs from replicating, e.g:

```
function(doc, req){
    return !doc._deleted
}
```

---

**To exclusively preserve docs with an `archive` attribute set**, you need to adjust your filter function:

```
function(doc, req){
    return !doc._deleted && doc.archive
}
```

*However*, archiving a document now consists of two steps:

1. saving it with the `archive` attribute set to your localDB, triggering its replication to your "data" database (and thus triggering its replication to the "backup" database)
2. actually deleting the document from the localDB, propagating the delete to your "data" database (with the filter function preventing the delete to propagate to the "backup" database) **after confirming replication to the "data" database** due to possible fast-forwards in couchdb's [replication protocol](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/TouchDB-iOS/wiki/Replication-Algorithm).

Comment: I'm still missing something... Let's say I have a doc which I would like to archive. In my application (don't forget I'm using PouchDB that syncs automatically with filters if needed) so in my application I set my doc to be archived. The application will then delete the doc. So a solution (please confirm if it's possible) would be to first set an archive parameter inside my doc to true and then delete the doc. With your solution, will PouchDB sync first the doc with the archive parameter and then delete it? Or will it only delete it? And will the continous replication occur to both revisions?

Comment: Pouchdb implements couchdb's replication algorithm (as mentioned in [couchdb docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/master/replication.html)), which is based on the `_changes` feed. Replication will process each document change seperately. This means there is no fast forward, so the proposed setup should work.

Comment: Perfect! One more thing to make sure I understood...when you say trigger replication, a continous replication should do the job right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: I investigated this further, reading about [couchdb's replication algorith](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/TouchDB-iOS/wiki/Replication-Algorithm). It seems there actually might happen fast forwarding during replication: only leaf nodes are replicated, skipping intermediate revisions. The solution is to save the document with a new `_id` and the `archive` attribute set before deleting the original document. Edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: So your solution is still problematic...from the application, how can you make sure the replication happened? In my app, as soon as I set the archive parameter to true, I update the doc with this parameter set to true. Just after that, without doing any check, I delete the doc. If my application was offline, what will be replicated to couchdb; the update and the delete or the delete ONLY? Then the replication (within same instance but other DB) will only try to replicate the delete? Is it what you're saying?

Comment: Sadly, yes. If the last local revision in an offline db is a deleted doc, only the delete will propagate.

I'm terribly sorry -- up till now, I didn't know about the fast forwards in the replication protocol. Please accept my appologies for the misinformation I was spreading. 

However, the first variant of my answer still fits your original problem
1. create document on local db
2. replicate local db to data db (thus replicating to backup db)
3. After few days, delete document from local db
4. replicate local db to data db, triggering deletion on data db (but preserving document in backup db)

Comment: No problem! the issue in your answer is definitely number 3 (after few days). You're still not sure your document has been sync'ed with the server...so is there a way to check in my app each sync'ed doc and if it is an update with the archive parameter, delete it? Can a plugin do that in PouchDB?

Comment: According to [PouchDB's documentation](http://pouchdb.com/api.html#replication), a replication will emit certain events: `uptodate` during _live_ (i.e. continuous) replication after the target db has been brought up-to-date and `complete` after finishing a _non-live_ (i.e. one-off) replication. You can hook into these events to a) `db.query()` all archived documents from the database and b) execute the final `db.remove()`. I don't see any reason why you couldn't put this into a plugin. You'd just have to wrap these things into your own `replicate.to` method.

Comment: This sounds good to me... I think we got it! I will try to implement that but in the meantime, please update your answer so I can validate it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think CouchDB has the exact solution you're looking for. One alternative, though, would be to just delete the document.  CouchDB stores the full revision history (up to 1000 revisions by default), but when it replicates, it will just replicate a stub: `{_deleted: true}`.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't really fit my expectations... Do you know if I could create this archiving system (copy the doc into another DB or view before deleting it) within an update handler function and call this function within the validate_doc_update function?

Comment: I don't think that's the purpose of the validate_doc_update function (it's for security or schema validation), but you could use the _changes feed in a separate process, watch for changes, and then push whatever you want to a separate database.

Comment: Also I want to better understand your problem, so is the worry that users will have too much data in their browser, and hence reach HTML5 storage quotas?  Because if so, then filtered replication might be a neat solution; you could filter on `!doc.archived` or whatever you want.

Comment: Yes, the reason is HTML5 storage quotas (the user can upload files). The problem with filters is that it's the user who tells when to archive a document and then delete it in its browser... so how could you delete the document in PouchDB only and change the status to archived in couchDB?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the _changes feed but how can I catch it within CouchDB and even if a javascript function is triggered (like in validate_doc_update), how do you move a doc to another database?

Comment: Nope, you'd need a separate process on the server side to poll CouchDB's _changes and then manually move documents to another DB.